# What's the code behind showAndWait in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafxports

I developed a small JavaFX application to be deployed in an Android device. Since, Alert is not yet supported in this current version of JavaFXPorts, I made my own implementaion of dialog. My problem is: **I do not know how to implement the showAndWait functionality. Can someone know the idea?**

Here's the code:

```
private static int status;
public static int showConfirm(String message){
    status = 0;

    black = new StackPane();
    black.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black; -fx-opacity: 0.7;");
    black.setPrefSize(Main.WIDTH, Main.HEIGHT);

    Label label = new Label(message);
    label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 22px;");
    label.setWrapText(true);

    Button okBtn = new Button("OK");
    okBtn.getStyleClass().add("terminal-button");
    okBtn.setPrefWidth(120);
    okBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            status = 1;
            Dialog.hide();
        }
    });

    Button cancelBtn = new Button("Cancel");
    cancelBtn.getStyleClass().add("terminal-button");
    cancelBtn.setPrefWidth(120);
    cancelBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            status = -1;
            Dialog.hide();
        }
    });

    HBox btnContainer = new HBox(10);
    btnContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    btnContainer.getChildren().addAll(okBtn,cancelBtn);

    VBox root = new VBox(30);
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
    root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    root.setPrefWidth(Main.WIDTH - 200);
    root.getChildren().addAll(label,btnContainer);

    Group container = new Group();
    container.getChildren().add(root);

    Main.PAGE.getChildren().add(black);
    Main.PAGE.getChildren().add(container);

    return status;
}
```

Comment: You could take a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs/1.0.1/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.java#Dialog.showAndWait%28%29)

Comment: hmm .. my first (very raw!) guess was to use runlater with a countDownLatch - but a quick search here revealed issues with Android .. out of ideas, sorry

Comment: Can you tell me more about the countDownLatch? What is it?

Comment: If I remember correctly (no time to dig out source code now) this is done by blocking the FX Appllication Thread and launching a nested FX Application Thread (i.e. a Thread for which `Platform.isFXApplicationThread()` returns `true`) in which the dialog is shown. This goes very deep into non-public API. If you cant use an existing call to `showAndWait`, I would strongly recommend just finding another solution: eg set a `BooleanProperty` when the dialog is hidden and register a listener with the property to execute the code you need to execute when it hides.

Comment: `Dialog.showAndWait()` internally uses call to `com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop()` and `com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop()`